# How to divide a value in a Cell with the Sum of an entire column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I want to divide a cell with the sum of the total value of the another cell in Power BI.

I wrote the formulae for the code but unfortunately this is not working.

Can someone help me out.

```
Agg Forecast Accuuracy = IFERROR(([Weightage Selection]/SUM([Weightage Selection])*[Forecast Accuracy]),0)
```

The excel formulae for this calculation is given below:

[image]

The calculation here is (2500/22500)*100.

The error I am getting is: `The SUM function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1.`

Attached the numbers used for calculation:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ALLSELECTED` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax

Example:

```
Agg Forecast Accuuracy =
  DIVIDE(
    [Weightage Selection],
    SUMX(ALLSELECTED('Sheet1'), [Weightage Selection])
  ) * [Forecast Accuracy]
```

Note also the use of `DIVIDE`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator

Comment: The output is not as per the expectation. The calculation is going wrong.

Comment: Then update your question with your data table and expected results. Power BI and Excel are two very different beasts.

Comment: I have added the image, but the calculation should be as shown above `(2500/22500)*100`, this is for the first row and the answer should be `11.11` but with the query which you shared I am getting the output `1.85`

Comment: Are you using a Calculated Column or a Measure?

Comment: Calculated Column. All the numbers which you see here are created by right clicking and selecting New Measure. I presume that means this is calculated column.

Comment: No it doesn't, it means these are Measures. Suggest your share a sample PBIX by uploading to public space and sharing the link (like One Drive, Google Drive, Drop Box etc...). Hard to tell what is Column, a Calculated Column, or a Measure.

Comment: Attached is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Az66rdBG2noGfLgdNqYwKlWY6RKvrzm7/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Access is given. Please let me know, if you can access it and if it was a Calculated Column or a Measure.

Comment: Try the above updated answer - needed to use `SUMX`.

Comment: It worked thank you. Can you tell me which if it was a calculated column or a measure? So that I can learn what I am using.

Comment: They were all Measures. Some would of been better off as Calculated Column (more Excel like). Please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.

Comment: Have done it. Thank you.